# HTML Cache control

Tags: html, xhtml, browser, caching

What is the difference between below 3 meta tags?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Do I need to use all those tags to avoid **browser caching**?

Comment: The way I see it, meta tags are only used for optional information, or at least that's how everyone uses them anymore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) which explains about all the different cache control headers (especially the part the explains that those [meta tags are largely useless](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META) and real HTTP headers are the way forwards).