# Browser image caching confusion

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control

Some of my images return these headers
[image: return headers]

Can anyone tell me when this image cache is going to expire and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cache-Control` value is the one that will be used - the image will expire from the cache after 604800 seconds. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799906/what-s-the-difference-between-expires-and-cache-control-headers) for more detail.

See also [here](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE_CONTROL):

```
When both Cache-Control and Expires are present, Cache-Control takes precedence
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. What I thought was that the max-age was added to the Expires header