# Published Visio Web Page but browser showing cached page

Tags: html, browser-cache, visio

I am publishing a Visio 2013 drawing to a site (using File->Export->Change File Type->Web Page (*.htm).  The website is checked into CM and then labeled.  My web server has a (ClearCase) view based on this label that automatically refreshes itself.

What I'm finding is that my browsers are always showing the cached (old) version of the pages.  I've been able to change my IE browser settings so that it always refreshes the cache (Internet Options->General Tab->Settings->Check for newer versions of stored pages = Every time I visit the webpage.  When I do this, I see the changes.

But, this isn't a real solution.  I don't want to have to tell my viewers to change their browser settings so it automatically refreshes.  Is there something I need to do to the page contents to tell all browsers to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle caching of browsers through the http response your server provides.

The `Cache-Control` field of the http response `no-cache` can prevent clients from caching the drawing if it is something you expect would be refreshed often: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Alternatively you can set the `Expires` field of the http response to expire after a day if the image would be updated on a periodic basis: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires)

The following question has a good comparison of the two: [what’s the difference between Expires and Cache-Control headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799906/what-s-the-difference-between-expires-and-cache-control-headers)

Comment: I'd rather not have to change the html that Visio generates each time I publish.  Surely there is something else going on.  I checked the source for cnn.com and it doesn't have anything regarding no-cache and I'm sure that page is changing by the minute.  FYI, I know little about web development.